# Different kind of Apostrophe in python string comparison

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm trying to do a string search operation using python and my its not working because I have three different kind of Apostrophe in my text [image: images of apostrophes]. I imported by data from word documents. Example comparison text:

> Stimmt`s  and Stimmt’s or Stimmt's

They all return false when compared like

```
"’" == "'"
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this?

**EDIT :**

I think this difference in Apostrophe is caused by different such as utf-8 vs ascii (I imported by data from word documents). So replacing apostrophe is one solution but there might be other characters which might cause problem. So I'm looking for a way to make sure text is imported using proper encoding.

Comment: `is_apostrophe = lambda c: c in "\`'’"` won't work for you?

Comment: It might but I think changing encoding might be a better idea. Check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace all unusual forms of the apostrophe before doing anything else you avoid running into any problems:

`` df = df.replace("`|’", "'", regex=True) ``

Comment: df.loc[:,'column_name'] = df.loc[:,'column_name'].str.replace("`|’", "'", regex=True)
Worked for me instead, '.loc' for better efficiency.

Comment: Is `df.loc[:,'col_name']` faster than `df['col_name']`? Also, when writing my answer I was under the impression that there were several if not all columns that needed this transformation, hence I wrote it so that it is applied to the whole dataframe.

Comment: df.loc is proper way to do such tasks. You might get 'SettingWithCopyWarning' or other similar warnings when using df['col_name']. I think .loc is supposed to be faster as well but I didn't check on my data. Pandas has a page comparing those two.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest solution will be to preprocess your data and use only one of them (e.g. replace all " ’ " with " ' " ). The characters are actually different from each other and that is the reason why you get False when comparing them. Another option is to define a Constant or an enum of a lsit type, such as:

```
APOSTROPHE = ["'","’" ...]
```

and then check if the symbol is in the list.